# Make static for non-static method

Tags: java, methods, non-static

First, maybe my title was wrong, any body please correct it for my exact problem.
And sorry about my English if that bugs you.
Here is my MainFram class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{
    public static JTextField checksum;
    public MainFrame(){
        createComponents();
        actionEvent();
    }
    private void createComponents(){
    ....
    }
    private void actionEvent(){
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (ae.getSource() == btnExem){
                actionEvent.btnPerformed(ae);
            }
            else if (ae.getSource() == jfBrowser){
            .........
            }
        }
    }
    copyBtn.addActionListener(al);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setResizable(false);
    }
```

actionEvent class:

```
public class actionEvent extends MainFrame{
//example
    public static void btnPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    checksum.setText("");
    }
```

I want to set private for checksum property in MainFrame class, I write a method setChecksumText in MainFrame class:

```
public void setChecksumText(String t){
        this.checksum.setText(t);
    }
```

But IDE show that btnPerformed must be static, so I cannot use setChecksumText method that is non-static.
How can I fix it?

Comment: You should define it as `protected  JTextField checksum;`

Comment: You're calling a non-static object in a static context. You extend the class, call the method you made to change the text.

Comment: Ironicly, the only really bad English is where you say it makes us chronic. Chronic means long-term or persisting.

Comment: Lol, I didn't mean that ironic was the correct term. Ironic means the opposite of what you expect, sorta. Use "if that bugs you".

Comment: @MaxZoom okay, but how can i use setChecksumText method in btnPerformed()? that sound be professional. maybe

Comment: @CaffeineToCode Editted bro :D

Comment: As `ActionEvent` class extends from `MainFrame` you can use the field directly `checksum.setText(..)`

Comment: @MaxZoom see my another question bellow please

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `static` to `setChecksumText()`. Note the checksum is `static`, it exists only once, not once per object, this means we don't access it with `this` but by the class name (you can omit the class if variable is in the same class):

```
private static JTextField checksum;

public static void setChecksumText(String t) {
    checksum.setText(t); // or: MainFrame.checksum.setText(t);
}
```